# PDO_sqlite не работает

Tags: pdo, php

в php.ini драйвер pdo_sqlite подключен. phpinfo то же показывает подключение. Но любая работа с PDO, в браузер выводит чистую страницу.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок

Comment: Скорее вскоре исполнение происходит с фатальной ошибкой, но Вы этого не видите из-за отключенного вывода ошибок.